# What do I reduce this transducer with?

Tags: clojure, transducer

```
(defn multiply-xf
  []
  (fn [xf]
    (let [product (volatile! 1)]
      (fn
        ([] (xf))
        ([result]
         (xf result @product)
         (xf result))
        ([result input]
         (let [new-product (* input @product)]
           (vreset! product new-product)
           (if (zero? new-product)
             (do
               (println "reduced")
               (reduced ...)) <----- ???
             result)))))))
```

This is a simple transducer which multiples numbers. I am wondering what would be the `reduced` value to allow early termination?

I've tried `(transient [])` but that means the transducer only works with vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want this transducer to produce a running product sequence and terminate early if the product reaches zero. Although in the example the reducing function `xf` is never called in the 2-arity *step* function, and it's called twice in the *completion* arity.

```
(defn multiply-xf
  []
  (fn [rf]
    (let [product (volatile! 1)]
      (fn
        ([] (rf))
        ([result] (rf result))
        ([result input]
         (let [new-product (vswap! product * input)]
           (if (zero? new-product)
             (reduced result)
             (rf result new-product))))))))
```

Notice for early termination, we don't care what `result` is. That's the responsibility of the reducing function `rf` a.k.a `xf` in your example. I also consolidated `vreset!`/`@product` with `vswap!`.

```
(sequence (multiply-xf) [2 2 2 2 2])
=> (2 4 8 16 32)
```

It will terminate if the running product reaches zero:

```
(sequence (multiply-xf) [2 2 0 2 2])
=> (2 4)
```

We can use `transduce` to sum the output. Here the reducing function is `+`, but your transducer doesn't need to know anything about that:

```
(transduce (multiply-xf) + [2 2 2 2])
=> 30
```

> I've tried `(transient [])` but that means the transducer only works with vectors.

This transducer also doesn't need to concern itself the type of sequence/collection it's given.

```
(eduction (multiply-xf) (range 1 10))
=> (1 2 6 24 120 720 5040 40320 362880)
(sequence (multiply-xf) '(2.0 2.0 0.5 2 1/2 2 0.5))
=> (2.0 4.0 2.0 4.0 2.0 4.0 2.0)
(into #{} (multiply-xf) [2.0 2.0 0.5 2 1/2 2 0.5])
=> #{2.0 4.0}
```

This can be done without transducers as well:

```
(take-while (complement zero?) (reductions * [2 2 0 2 2]))
=> (2 4)
```

Comment: thanks, that does solve the problem. however, the transducer I was trying to write would produce a single output. is that wrong to create a transducer that way?

Comment: You can use a transducer to produce a single output, as in the `transduce` example above that sums the products. “They are independent from the context of their input and output sources and specify only the essence of the transformation in terms of an individual element.” So building the intent of producing a single value inside your transducer wouldn’t seem advisable.

Comment: Ah, yes, that explains. There was a flaw in my assumptions on how transducers can work. :)